# Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'value' of type 'object' supplied to 'TextInput'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When I change the input to '' and submit it (in the TextInput) I have the following error: "Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'value' of type 'object' supplied to 'TextInput'"

```
        <TextInput 
          style={styles.input} 
          autoCapitalize='none'
          onChange={email => this.setState({email})}
          value={this.state.email}
        >
```

Comment: Could you show me your state ?

Comment: kindly add your state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onChange()` method should be as follow:

```js
        <TextInput 
          style={styles.input} 
          autoCapitalize='none'
          onChange={(e) => {
            this.setState({
              email: e.nativeEvent.text
            })
          }}
          value={this.state.email}
        >
```

Or you can just use `onChangeText()` to assing entered text into your state as below :

```js
<TextInput 
          style={styles.input} 
          autoCapitalize='none'
          onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({ email })}
          value={this.state.email}
        >
```

More [doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#onchange) here.

Answer (score 0):

if you have defined your state like this

```
     state={email:''} // or
     this.state={email:''}
```

changed code

```
    <TextInput 
      style={styles.input} 
      autoCapitalize='none'
      onChange={e=> this.setState({email:e.target.value})}
      value={this.state.email}
      >
```